# Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory alternative for EF non-Core?

Tags: entity-framework

I have inherited a large legacy project which makes broad-use of Entity Framework (non-Core) and has literally no tests. It leverages some features which will not allow me to upgrade to ASP.NET Core or EF Core -- at least not yet. Anyway, I would like to build sufficient testing to give me confidence in the code. This is when I realized that Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory will not be available to me. Are there any alternatives which will allow me to unit test EF non-Core in the same way?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you use SQLite provider with "in memory" feature in non-Core EF?

Comment: You could create a new base class with generic DbSets and an interface for your datacontext, so that you can unit test your business logic with a mocked datacontext. I don't know the "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory Way", but if that sounds sufficient for you, I can post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered EFFORT (https://entityframework-effort.net/) which is downloadable as a NuGet (make sure you reference the right version). It is basically like Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory but also works in non-Core. It works because you change the test project's app.config to point to an EFFORT-provided in-memory SQL provider. My test cases just work as one would expect without any custom code (I use it like the real thing). The only downside I've seen is my EFFORT test cases are kind of slow (200+ms). In any case, my tests should be able to remain unchanged when I finally can make the transition to ASP.NET Core.